# Remove HTML markup from logstash input

Tags: html, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am struggling with data manipulation in logstash version 5.1, where some of the data come from open text fields with HTML markups. Most of the time it comes with only one marker, like this:

<.p> XYZ <./p>

and I am dealing with it using Grok.

but when it comes like this:

<.p><.b><.strong> XYZ <./strong><./b><./p>

simple grok cant filter it out.

My question is if there is a built-in filter for HTML markup or do i have to develop my own using regular expressions? Or do you know if in versions prior 5.1 is it possible ?

Comment: From what I know and have seen there is no such filter. https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns. So, it seems to me that you'll have to write your own pattern matching and will always need to modify it for all new scenarios of data that the client is saying this should not be there. PITA..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the HTML, you can use this:

```
mutate {  
  gsub => [
    "fieldname", "<.*?>", ""
  ]
}
```

Comment: @GoutamS Have you replaced `fieldname` by the appropriate field name? If yes, what's not working (maybe ask a question)?

Comment: Yes I did that :)